# How div width follow table width?

Tags: html

I have code
https://jsfiddle.net/ang3lwish/dnt4pv6m/2/

```
<div style="border:1px solid yellow;display:block;">
<table border=1 align="center">
    <tr>
<th>No.</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Address</th>
<th>Gender</th>
<th>Email</th>  
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            1.
        </td>
        <td>
            Anto
        </td>
        <td>
            Padang
        </td>
         <td>
            Male
        </td>
         <td>
            anto@gmail.com
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br>

</div>
```

I want the div width (in line yellow) is follow table width?

But i don't know how to set css?

Answer (score 1):

Make table width `100%` Add this is your `table` tag

```
<table border=1 align="center" width="100%">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the table to be fit to the div you need to put 100% width to the table
`<table width="100%">` the table adjust itself depending on the div. cheers :)

Comment: ohh just the same logic the table must fit the container take a look at here https://jsfiddle.net/dnt4pv6m/5/

Comment: in your fiddle that the table out of the div .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to follow the yellow line(i.e your div) without css then use width=100% in your table attribute but again only using this will not help you much for setting the table in div properly so better use this:
in css:

```
.pad
{
 padding-top: 25px;
 padding-right: 50px;//set as you like them//
 padding-bottom: 25px;
 padding-left: 50px;
}
```

and then include this class in table as:

```
<table border=1 align="center" class="pad">
```

Comment: I'm sorry . i mean the div width is to be fit with the table width..is impossible?

Comment: nothing is impossible .you can just make the padding go zero and then see if it solve your problem.@ZAJ

Comment: padding on div tag or table?

Comment: ..i have try set padding to zero (0) px and nothing was happen.

Comment: do the padding for the table tag @ZAJ